# Issue when try to login at instagram with genymotion android emulator

Tags: android-emulator, instagram, genymotion

I installed genymotion with playstore and then instagram but when I try to login in instagram app it always returns a blank popup with only a button "dimiss".

I can login at facebook but in instagram not.

[image]

I tried everthing but it is impossible to login instagram app.

Could someone help me with some hints, please?

Answer (score 0):

if possible, try with a more recent android version. Anything newer than 7.0 should be ok

Answer (score 0):

You could update Genymotion to latest version. If that doesn't solve the issue, use the latest version of Android (8.1). If the issue still occurs, contact Genymotion.